# Filtering a row based on the first four digits and last four digits of number is one column

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been using in some macros coding to filter rows based on the values in one column.  This has worked for what I've done in a general sense, but I'm needing to do some things that are a little more specific with the same stuff. What I have been using is follows this:

```
 Dim c As Range, x As Integer
'other code here
Set c = shtMaster.Range("Y5")  'Start search in Row 5
'other code  here
While Len(c.Value) > 0
        'If value in column Y ends with specified value,copy to report sheet
        If c.Value Like "*2130" Or c.Value Like "*0853" Then
'rest of macro follows
```

I've been trying to mess with the If line so that I can add conditions for the first four and last four digits instead of just using values based on the last four.  For example, I may want to search Column Y for all values whose first four digits are "1234*" but whose last four digits are not "*5678".  So if I had a spreadsheet with:

> ```
>      Column Y
> ```
>
> Row 1     12345678
>   Row 2     12341234
>   Row 3     12340000

then it would pull rows 2 and 3 but not row 1. I would like to use the structure above since that's how everything is already written, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Is what I want to do possible with the structure I already have written? If so, any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If c.Value Like "1234*" And Not c.Value Like "*5678" Then 

'Values start with 1234 and do not end in 5678.

End If
```

Comment: I do not know why, but this simply is not working. This is what I started with but it simply will not pull the rows like you would think it should.  I've tried working with parentheses and regrouping the line, but it just will not pull the rows that it should.

Comment: What's an example of some of the bad data its pulling back?

Comment: Lol. I figured it out. Too much working on different coding at the same time I guess. The other stuff I am working on uses the same basis for filtering data but uses multiple .values. This actually does work just as you and I thought it should. I mixed the d.value and c.value so of course it wasn't pulling what it was supposed to. :p